# How to export current network configuration that I have on my System Preferences on mac os x?

Tags: networking, mac, terminal, services, system-preferences

I want to export all my configuration on my services on System Preferences and change all of them by export and importing all at ones.
How to export and import all services and configuration for each service on Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

You can export network configuration for VPN connections through system preferences - Network - click on the gear icon on the left side.

But I think the you need to export all your network configurations, and that no possible through the GUI, you can do this but copying a specific file and paste it in the same location on the same machine or another one.

File path Library - Preferences - System configuration - preferences.plist

Comment: This file read on OS boot up? and if I save one version of this file and change the setting and then get a backup from new configuration so can I see my changes by "Ifconfig" command on terminal?